Francis Bacon's Of Truth and his view of the Sceptics
Of Truth by Francis Bacon begins as follows:

"What is truth?" said jesting Pilate, and would not stay for an answer. Certainly, there be that delight in giddiness, and count it a bondage to fix a belief, affecting free-will in thinking as well as in acting. And though the sects of philosophers of that kind be gone, yet there remain certain discoursing wits which are of the same veins, though there be not so much blood in them as was in those of the ancients.

In the OUP edition (ISBN 978-0-19-954079-2) the notes say that the sects of philosophers refers to the Sceptics. (It is written with an upper-case S, so I guess it means Pyrrhonism?) I'm not sure what Bacon is saying here about the Sceptics. The above passage seem critical to me, i.e. that Bacon does not agree with the Sceptics. However, a few sentences later when he admonishes people's natural inclination to lie, he refers to Lucian's Lover of Lies, in which Tychiades, a sceptic (lower-case?) and the hero of the piece, shows up the gullibility and superstition of the other characters. By making this reference Bacon seems to be putting the Sceptics in a positive light.
What is Bacon's opinion of the Sceptics? Is it a nuanced view, in the same way that one might admire a good ligitator for their ability to pick apart flawed arguments, but at the same time criticise them for not fixing to one opinion – pointing out problems but not providing solutions, so to speak? And as a secondary question: Am I conflating Pyrrhonism with more general philsophical scepticism?

See Bacon and skepticism

You should look up para-Vedic skepticism (Hindustan). One particular individual pops to mind, the now forgotten Sanjaya Belathiputta. Bacon's probably talking about musavadabhaya
